# Find primes such that $\frac{1}{p_1 - p_2 -p_3}= \frac{1}{p_2} + \frac{1}{p_3}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all primes $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$ that satisfy the following equation:

$\frac{1}{p_1 - p_2 -p_3}= \frac{1}{p_2} + \frac{1}{p_3}$

Really lost on how I can approach this question. Would appreciate some guidance to get me started on this problem. Also, this exercise is listed after the chapter on Quadratic Residue/Legendre symbols so if there is a way to implement it into this problem, that would be great. I still welcome other methods though :)

Comment: Another hint: show that $p_2+p_3$ divides $p_2p_3$

Comment: are $p_1, p_2, p_3$ supposed to be distinct? If not $5,2,2$ is a solution.

Comment: @sku yes, they are supposed to be distinct but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RHS = $\frac{p_2+p_3}{p_2p_3}$. Given the numerator of LHS is $1$, we have to assume $ (p_2+p_3)| p_2p_3$.

Let $p_2p_3 = k(p_2 + p_3) \implies p_2|k, p_3|k \implies k \ge p_2p_3 \implies 1 \ge (p_2 + p_3)$ which is not true.

Comment: $p_2p_3 = k(p_2 + p_3)$ does not implies $p_2|k, p_3|k $. A counterexample: $p_2=p_3=2$

Comment: Yes but there is no solution with that option. Thanks